Finding pole by inspection in second order circuit

How do I find the poles in this circuit quickly?
The zero is easy to find since I can just find what impedance causes the node to go to zero individually for each branch.

Here's a couple examples of how to do it graphically. Sorry for the low quality image.
In the second example, the pole is the intersection of \$\frac{1}{sC_2}\$ and a resistive section with magnitude equal to \$\frac{1}{s(C_1+C_2)}, s=\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\$. The pole can be rewritten as \$\frac{1}{R(C_1 || C_2)}\$. This is likely the actual expression of the pole you would find analytically. It simplifies to \$\frac{1}{R_1C_2}\$ in the first example because \$C_2 \ll C_1\$. The parallel symbol here is a math operator not a circuit description.



How did you figure out what the resistive section is ?

It is the magnitude of the LF capacitive segment at the first zero.
